# Positioning CSS Class from jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using a simple form with jQuery Validation Plugin 
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js
(http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

When **label .error** class gets called it appears below the input field. How can i make this appear inline with the normal *label* name

**Link:**
i.imgur.com/KchiGeF.jpg

```
<label>Your Name</label>
<input name="phone" id="phone" required type="text"  size="40" >
```

**JQuery function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength:10
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I'll suggest to make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you declare your rules, change the errorElement.

```
errorElement: "span"
```

By default it's a `label`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: "span",
        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength:10
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there any way make it call above the input so its inline with the 'Phone' Label or would that require changing the js? At the moment .label has 10px top-bottom padding with 14px font

Comment: You could try using CSS pseudo class, or wrap the label around the input. But that might require a javascript change

Comment: Also, please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your issue well enough :)

Comment: When i wrap it around the input it just displays it inline : ( i'll see if i can position it relative